# TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not str (python, phonenumbers)

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь использовать phonenumbers, но как мне вызывать исключение для того, чтобы оно отдавалось обратно в `post` форму? выдает ошибку `%i format: a number is required, not str` вместо того, чтобы показать это, как ошибку о неправильном заполнении в форме на сайте

**models.py**

```
import phonenumbers

def validate_phone_number(value):
    try:
        z = phonenumbers.parse(value, None)
    except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
        print('NOT VALID 0')
        raise ValidationError(_('%(value) is not a valid phone number'), params={'value': value},)
    if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
        print('NOT VALID')
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value) is not a valid phone number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )

class Storehouses(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[validate_phone_number], unique=True, max_length=17)
```

**views.py**

```
class StorehouseSettingsAddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'storehouse/settings/storehouse_settings_add.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get work good
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formOne = StorehouseAddCategoryForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')

        if formOne.is_valid():
            form_one = formOne.save(commit=False)
            form_one.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('storehouse_settings_add'))
        else:
            print('NotValid')
            context = self.get_context_data()
            formOne.prefix = 'one_form'
            context.update({'formOne': formOne})
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: может `z = phonenumbers.parse(value, None)` выдает другое исключение (не `phonenumbers.NumberParseException`), которое Вы не обрабатываете?

Comment: именно это исключение отрабатывает и дальше выдает ошибку уже при return self.render_to_response(context)